# Error when exporting FeatureCollection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, error, features, feature-collection

I got an Error: "**Invalid argument: 'collection' must be a FeatureCollection. (Error code: 3)**", when I was trying to export FeatureCollection. *Geometry* was a rectangle I draw to clip the featurecolletion.

```
var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection('LARSE/GEDI/GEDI02_A_002/GEDI02_A_2021244154857_O15413_04_T05622_02_003_02_V002')
              .filterBounds(geometry);
dataset = dataset.style({color: 'black',  pointSize: 1});
Map.setCenter(-64.88, -31.77, 15);
Map.addLayer(dataset);

Export.table.toDrive({
collection: dataset,
description:"GEDI",
fileFormat: 'csv'
});
```

However, it worked if I replace 'collection: dataset' with 'collection: ee.FeatureCollection('LARSE/GEDI/GEDI02_A_002/GEDI02_A_2021244154857_O15413_04_T05622_02_003_02_V002').filterBounds(geometry)'. I'm not sure why I can't export dataset here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `dataset.style()` doesn't just add styling information; it converts the `FeatureCollection` into an `Image` with the features painted using that style.

- If you want to export features to a table, don't call `style()`. There is no  way to convey the style information in a CSV, anyway.
- If you want to see a picture with the specific style you have chosen, you will have to `Export.image` instead of `Export.table`.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks so much. It's very clear now.